# How to change window.location on modal open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have two modals: one is for login action and another one is for registration action.

In login modal there is a link "Not yet registered?" that opens a registration modal. And in registration modal there is a link "Already a member?" that opens a login modal.

When login modal is opened I want `windows.location` to be changed to `/login` and when registration modal is opened I want `windows.location` to be changed to `/registration`. And I want Back and Forward buttons of a browser work correctly, so that they change modals from `/login` to `/registration` back and forth.

1) What is the name of this functionality (if it has some standard name)?

2) Do famous frameworks like Bootstrap or http://pgwjs.com/pgwmodal/ or others provide this functionality out of the box? Which one?

3) How can I create that functionality myself?

Comment: use this customizable jquery ui plugin http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be looking for Single Page Application functionality.  One option could be changing the value of `window.location.hash` instead of `window.location` so you're not triggering a page refresh.  Browser history will still work as expected.

One potential drawback for you though (or not) would be that the URL would look like `example.com/#/login` or `example.com/#/registration`.

You could just use a library like Bootstrap for the modal and include logic to change `window.location.hash` when it's toggled.

Hope that helps.